# Reference or documentation for Citrix XenServer Powershell cmdlets

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, citrix, powershell-cmdlet, hypervisor

I just started writing powershell scripts for Citrix XenServer. However, I can only find code snippets and this [cmdlet poster](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.x-tech.at%2Fdownload_file.php%3Ffile%3D%252Ffiles%252FCitrix_XenServer_6.0_CmdLet_Poster.pdf&ei=KfXqT-27IoPIsga4r_3zBQ&usg=AFQjCNFQQ0EmfJLoZSLCzDZoguJW11Sitw) on the internet.

Where can I find a full documentation with explanations and possible parameters directly from Citrix? All APIs and references available are only valid for the command line.

Thank you!

Comment: In powershell `get-help cmdletname -full` can help?

Comment: thanks, unfortunately this only works for some cmdlets like Get-XenServer:VM. When trying to get help for Get-XenServer:VM.HardShutdown it says there wouldn't be any help available. Or is there a difference to the first command?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can help more, never user XenServer cmdlets.

Comment: ok, no problem...your hint with the powershell help was useful as well. It's just a bit weak of citrix that they don't provide a clear reference as they apparently do for the XenDesktop SnapIn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I could find was a reference for the underlying SDK. The cmdlets are apparently implemented using the original XenServer management API, and that API is documented. You can find a reference for it here:

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX130426

I couldn't find anything more than that reference poster for the cmdlets however.

It's not ideal, but you can use .NET Reflector to look at the underlying code of the cmdlets to see how they are using the XenServer management API and then cross reference the docs for that API.

Comment: sry, I forgot to answer last year. Thanks, I could finish my project by cross referencing these two APIs. Unfortunately a bit inconvinient - Citrix really has to improve its API documentation.